# Prioritized threads not doing their job in expected order

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

at school I was given an assignment to build a simple application to show how threads prioritizing work. Problem is that threads I fire doesn't stick to priorities set and finish at random (or it looks like so).

Here's code for my main window:

```
namespace ThreadsShowtime
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private SuperThread _lowest;
        private SuperThread _below;
        private SuperThread _normal;
        private SuperThread _above;
        private SuperThread _highest;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _lowest = new SuperThread(ThreadPriority.Lowest, elipseLowest, Dispatcher, lowestLbl);
            _below = new SuperThread(ThreadPriority.BelowNormal, elipseBelow, Dispatcher, belowLbl);
            _normal = new SuperThread(ThreadPriority.Normal, elipseNormal, Dispatcher, normalLbl);
            _above = new SuperThread(ThreadPriority.AboveNormal, elipseAbove, Dispatcher, aboveLbl);
            _highest = new SuperThread(ThreadPriority.Highest, elipseHighest, Dispatcher, highestLbl);

            _lowest.Start();
            _below.Start();
            _normal.Start();
            _above.Start();
            _highest.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

And SuperThread class code:

```
namespace ThreadsShowtime
{
    public class SuperThread
    {
        private readonly Stopwatch _stopwatch;
        public readonly Thread Thread;

        public SuperThread(ThreadPriority thp, Shape sh, Dispatcher dispatcher, ContentControl lbl)
        {
            Thread = new Thread(() => DummyMethod(dispatcher, sh, lbl)) {Priority = thp};
            _stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        }

        public long Elapsed { get; private set; }
        public double ElapsedSeconds => Elapsed / 1000.0;


        private void DummyMethod(Dispatcher dispatcher, Shape sh, ContentControl lbl)
        {
            _stopwatch.Start();
            dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                sh.Fill = Brushes.GreenYellow;
            }, DispatcherPriority.Normal);    

            for (var idx = 0; idx < 30000; idx++) Console.WriteLine(idx);

            dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                sh.Fill = Brushes.OrangeRed;
            }, DispatcherPriority.Normal);

            _stopwatch.Stop();
            Elapsed = _stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

            dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                lbl.Content = ElapsedSeconds;
            }, DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);

        }

        public void Start()
        {
            Thread.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

The output of this application looks like that:
[image: Output]

Why does that happen?
Thank you very much for any help provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of `dispatcher.Invoke()` and `Console.WriteLine()`, your code is effectively single threaded. What you see is the slightly unpredictable results of queuing the threads. Those queues are not FIFO.

To see the proper effect, benchmark some code that is purely CPU bound, like a Sort(). Make sure they run for > 200 ms, smaller runs are meaningless.

Comment: Now it feels like real multithreading :). Thank you very much for your time and help!